# API - Blazor server - foreign key ICollection is always null - EF core

Tags: api, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm new to API and Blazor and I'm trying to follow this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Below you can see my models and code.

Model:

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
 public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set;}
}
```

API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await context.Students
                .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.StudentId == id);

            //var result = await context.Students
            //    .Where(s => s.StudentId == id)
            //    .Select(s => new
            //    {
            //        Student = s,
            //        Enrollment = s.Enrollments

            //    })
            //    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error receiving data from database");
        }
    }
```

Student model in Blazor server

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

My Blazor Student base:

```
public class StudentDetailsBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IEnrollmentService EnrollmentService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IStudentService StudentService { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public List<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Id = Id ?? "1";
        Student = await StudentService.GetStudent(int.Parse(Id));
        Enrollments = (await EnrollmentService.GetEnrollmentBySID(int.Parse(Id))).ToList();
        //Student = (await StudentService.GetStudent(int.Parse(Id))).ToList();
    }
}
```

And my Student display page:

```
@if (Student == null)
    {
        <p>Loading ...</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Enrollment Date</th>
                        <th>All enrollments</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Student.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@Student.LastName</td>
                        <td>@Student.EnrollmentDate</td>
                        @foreach (var i in Student.Enrollments)
                        {
                            <td>@i.Course.Title</td>
                            <td>@i.Grade</td>
                        }
                    </tr> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
```

I've tried to google the problem and i can not figure out what i'm doing wrong. **My Student.Enrollments in always null.** Which causes my Blazor server to throw an error.

When i test my API with Postman it's working fine.

Hopefully someone will point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

Thank you.
Kind regards.

Comment: [Route("{id:int}")] should be {id}

Comment: Dear DannyThunder,

I doubt that's the reason for my null foreign key, as it's accaptable to use constrains in routing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Never the less i tried to change it just to id, but Enrollments is still null.

Kind regards.

Comment: Oh! Yea! Sorry about that! If you debug the collection, what is the content, and what is the key you're looking up?

Comment: Sorry, dont quite understand what you mean. When i debug my result in API the Student.Enrollments are populated. But when i call my API in Blazor and save the results in Student, the Enrollments are null.

Comment: Student.cs got [JsonIgnore], how come?

Comment: It's there to break the cycle. Since i have a foreign key - collection of Enrollments in Students and in Enrollments i have a foreign key of Student it just cycles from one to other if i dont break it and then i receive json error maximum of 32 cycles etc...